# wordpress .htaccess & .htpasswd issue

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, .htpasswd

I have a strange issue here. My client site is suspended due to spam messages by one.com. After deleting the comments, the technical support guy told me to generate .htaccess and .htpasswd file by using one.com's support page and upload it into root. Deleted old files and uploaded the new files a per the supporting guy. But site shown an internal error, then the technical guy said 'delete' both files and try. Then the home page is loading but inner pages showing 404 error.

Anyone here have a solution for this? this is the site http://www.jayabhattacharjirose.com/

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you re-save your permalinks?

Comment: @mevius :- Yes, I searched googled for a solution. Actually the link showing http://www.jayabhattacharjirose.com/jaya/blog, and if we remove that '/jaya',  it will work, but I don't know where to do that. I checked in permalink, but there link has no extra folder name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem with permalinks. Try the one of the following three solutions.

1: Set your Permalinks back to default, if things start working as expected then try re-setting Permalinks back to what you want.

2: Try going in your Dashboard to Settings > Permalinks. You don't need to change anything on the Permalinks page, but just click Save Changes at the bottom. Then check your site to see if that fixed it.

3: Try changing options on the Permalinks page if you want to change the way the URL looks from p=### to the /date/page format or others.

Comment: I tried but not working, I think in the url, there is an extra folder name showing "/jaya" (inner pages), I think that's the problem.

Comment: yes if the pages are not in the same folder this will create a problem Like if home page is http://www.jayabhattacharjirose.com/ and other page is in http://www.jayabhattacharjirose.com/jaya/other-page then this will be a problem. So move your pages to the same URL.

Comment: Yes, its an issue from the server side, the files and links are changed. Now resolved it. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Reset your permalink to default and then again set it your required permalink structure so that WordPress creates a new required .htaccess file for it.

And if you have backup of your project then try to use the old .htaccess file.

Comment: I don't have a backup of .htaccess file :( , I have back-up of that prject only

Comment: No issues, wordpress can create it for you. Just rename the current .htaccess file and then follow the permalink reset process and check if the new .htaccess file created or not..
And if not then create a blank .htaccess file and give it 777 permissions and follow the permalink reset process.

After then check your website links

Comment: Thanks Jenis, Let me try it.

Comment: After having a look at your website, it seems like permalinks are working fine, but "/jaya/" is adding with urls.

So please make sure the home and siteurl both options of wp_options table have this url : http://www.jayabhattacharjirose.com/ not this
http://www.jayabhattacharjirose.com/jaya/